# Keeping iPhone network connections alive while in inactive state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sockets, background

I am working on a chat client app that connects to a chat server. When I receive any pop-up notifications (for example, a SMS message), the iPhone puts the app into the inactive state - great. The problem I have encountered is that once the notification is dismissed, the app has lost all network connections. I've read other places that this shouldn't happen, but I'm not sure what I'm missing!

Here is a snippet of the code I am using to create the read and write streams.

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {

//set up read and write streams
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

//connect to host at this address and this port
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"somewebsite.org", 3333, &readStream, &writeStream);

//open socket connection
inputStream = [(NSInputStream *)readStream retain];
outputStream = [(NSOutputStream *)writeStream retain];
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
}
```

Network connection is also lost when the app is sent to the background. I would like to fix that too, but the main issue right now is the pop-up notifications disconnecting the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing in your application's "applicationWillResignActive:" method? You might consider suspending the connection, then resuming on it once the app is active again. Either way you should be doing something in that method.

Hope that helps.